# How to mock props that actually are connected action creators of Redux?

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, sinon, enzyme

In an integration test I want to test that a connected action creator gets called.

```
describe('SomeContainer', () => {
  let subject, store, fancyActionCreator

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = createStore(combineReducers({ /* ... */ }))
    fancyActionCreator = sinon.spy()
    const props = {
      fancyActionCreator
    }
    subject = (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <SomeContainer {...props} />
      </Provider>
    )
  })

  it('calls fancyActionCreator on mount', () => {
    mount(subject)
    expect(fancyActionCreator.callCount).to.equal(1)
  })
}
```

The action creator is called inside `componentWillMount` and works as expected beyond the test environment.

The problem is that the original action creator gets called in the test and does not get mocked away properly.

I've the feeling it's because of Redux's `connect()` method that is replacing the spy:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, { fancyActionCreator })(SomeContainer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mounted your component with store. If you take return value from mount call, it gives you enzyme wrapper for react element. This wrapper can be used to dispatch actions against store:

```
const enzymeWrapper = mount(subject)
enzymeWrapper.node.store.dispatch({ type: "ACTION", data: "your fake data" });
```

But this is more integration type of testing, because you are using reducers as well as connection of Redux store state to your properties.

This is the only test I could come up to test connection of Redux store state to component properties. If you fake properties somehow else, you might cover your component logic, but you are missing piece that is connecting properties to store.

I would suggest to separate your components into presentational vs container components. Presentational don't need to use store and thus you can hammer its logic just by passing different properties. Container component concern is to connect store to presentational components. So for container component you would use type of testing I described.

REACTION ON COMMENT:

Actually usage of `mount` vs `shallow` for presentational/unconnected component is not that that straight forward. Sometimes you are using sub-components on your presentational component that needs to be rendered by mount (e.g. react-select needs DOM for some reason).

But generally yes, one should strive to use `shallow` for presentational components, unless you realize you need `mount` :).